# I've mistyped my client's name while creating iCloud account on his behalf

Tags: icloud

I've mistyped my client's name while creating an iCloud account on his behalf (for example: instead `name.surname@icloud.com` I typed `nmae.surname@icloud.com`), and before notice, the mistake, enrolled the account for Apple Developer Program.

Now, I need to fix this mistake but do not know if there is a way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would stop what I'm doing with the misnamed account, and contact Apple Developer Support. Apple's Developer Support contact page is here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/

Answer (score 1):

I have never dealt with this but the Apple Support page has this, might be worthy for you.

> **If you enter your email address incorrectly when you create your Apple ID**
>
> If you create your Apple ID with an email address that you can't verify, sign in to your Apple ID account page with the email address that you entered when you set up your Apple ID. Then you can change your Apple ID to the correct email address.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667

Comment: I think this should work if you created your AppleID with a custom email address, instead of an @icloud.com like. I've already read this doc but my AppleID page doesn't give me an option to change the mail. But I've recently changed my own AppleID from Gmail to iCloud, so I know where it should be and how it would work.